How would I calculate the days remaining from a date column
I have created a Microsoft List and I have a date expiry column and a days remaining column. I want a simple calculation to show the days remaining from the expiry, if its already expired, I just want it to say 'No days remaining'.
I found this script, firstly its not working and secondly I don't really know how its supposed to work, so I would like some information on that also:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(floor((Number(@currentField)-Number(Date((getMonth(@now)+1)+'.'+getDate(@now)+'.'+getYear(@now))))/(60*60*24*1000))>0,floor((Number(@currentField)-Number(Date((getMonth(@now)+1)+'.'+getDate(@now)+'.'+getYear(@now))))/(60*60*24*1000))+' day(s) remaining','no days remaining')"
}

I want it to be like the following:
Date of Expiry 20/07/24 - Days remaining = 3
Thanks

See the JSON example below. You may need to update the column names in the sample JSON. It checks if the [Date Column] is empty or not and then applies the conditional formatting.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(length([$ActivatedDT])>0,if(([$ActivatedDT]<@now),' No days remaining', ceiling((Number([$ActivatedDT])-Number(@now))/86400000) + ' Day(s) remaining') , '')",
  "style": {  
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "1.5em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}




Thanks again Matiur. I've tried this but its blank, I think its because my column name has spaces in it. I've tried adding x0020 as I was reading that's the code for space, but its still not working

Yes, that might be the case. If you can, post your JSON with the internal names of the columns, and I can review and update

@Addioioi, you can get the correct internal name of your column by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?. Then try using it in your JSON.
